# How to evaluate the model through Precision, recall and F1-measure

Tags: python, pytorch

I am currently working on a CSRNet model, trained the model and evaluate it by MAE and MSE now I would like to evaluate the said model through precision, recall and f1-measure and its visualization. Can some one help me how to add the piece of code in the train.py and model.py in order to calculate the above mentioned statistical parameters.

```
"Train.py"

import sys
import os

import warnings

from model import CSRNet

from utils import save_checkpoint

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

import numpy as np
import argparse
import json
import cv2
import dataset
import time

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'

Train_loss_list = []
#Val_MAE_list = []
k=0

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch CSRNet')

parser.add_argument('train_json', metavar='TRAIN',
                    help='path to train json')
parser.add_argument('test_json', metavar='TEST',
                    help='path to test json')

parser.add_argument('--pre', '-p', metavar='PRETRAINED', default=None,type=str,
                    help='path to the pretrained model')

parser.add_argument('gpu',metavar='GPU', type=str,
                    help='GPU id to use.')

parser.add_argument('task',metavar='TASK', type=str,
                    help='task id to use.')

def main():
    
    global args,best_prec1
    
    best_prec1 = 1e6
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.original_lr = 1e-7
    args.lr = 1e-7
    args.batch_size    = 1
    args.momentum      = 0.95
    args.decay         = 5*1e-4
    args.start_epoch   = 0
    args.epochs = 400
    args.steps         = [-1,1,100,150]
    args.scales        = [1,1,1,1]
    args.workers = 4
    args.seed = time.time()
    args.print_freq = 30
    with open(args.train_json, 'r') as outfile:        
        train_list = json.load(outfile)
    with open(args.test_json, 'r') as outfile:       
        val_list = json.load(outfile)
    
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = args.gpu
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.seed)
    
    model = CSRNet()
    
    model = model.cuda()
    
    criterion = nn.L1Loss(size_average=False).cuda()
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), args.lr,
                                momentum=args.momentum,
                                weight_decay=args.decay)

    if args.pre:
        if os.path.isfile(args.pre):
            print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(args.pre))
            checkpoint = torch.load(args.pre)
            args.start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
            best_prec1 = checkpoint['best_prec1']
            model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
            optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
            print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
                  .format(args.pre, checkpoint['epoch']))
        else:
            print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'".format(args.pre))
            
    for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.epochs):
        
        adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch)
        
        train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
        prec1 = validate(val_list, model, criterion)
        
        is_best = prec1 < best_prec1
        best_prec1 = min(prec1, best_prec1)
        print(' * best MAE {mae:.3f} '
              .format(mae=best_prec1))
        save_checkpoint({
            'epoch': epoch + 1,
            'arch': args.pre,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'best_prec1': best_prec1,
            'optimizer' : optimizer.state_dict(),
        }, is_best,args.task)
    x1 = range(0, args.epochs)
    x2 = range(0, args.epochs)
    y1 = Train_loss_list
    #y2 = Val_MAE_list
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None,
                       wspace=None, hspace=0.8)
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(x1, y1, label="Train Loss")
    plt.title('Train Loss vs. Epochs')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Losses')
    #plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    #plt.plot(x1, y2, label="Val MSE")
    #plt.title('MSE vs. epoches')
    #plt.xlabel('epochs')
    #plt.ylabel('MSE')
    plt.savefig("C:/Users/Gigabyte pc/Desktop/COUNTING/CSRNet-pytorch-master/PartA2_train_curve.jpg")




def train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch):
    
    losses = AverageMeter()
    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    data_time = AverageMeter()
    
    
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset.listDataset(train_list,
                       shuffle=True,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                   ]), 
                       train=True, 
                       seen=model.seen,
                       batch_size=args.batch_size,
                       num_workers=args.workers),
        batch_size=args.batch_size)
    print('epoch %d, processed %d samples, lr %.10f' % (epoch, epoch * len(train_loader.dataset), args.lr))
    
    model.train()
    end = time.time()
    
    for i,(img, target)in enumerate(train_loader):
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)
        
        img = img.cuda()
        img = Variable(img)
        output = model(img)
        
        
        
        
        target = target.type(torch.FloatTensor).unsqueeze(0).cuda()
        target = Variable(target)
        
        
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        
        losses.update(loss.item(), img.size(0))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()    
        
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()
        
        if i % args.print_freq == 0:
            print('Epoch: [{0}][{1}/{2}]\t'
                  'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Data {data_time.val:.3f} ({data_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'
                  .format(
                   epoch, i, len(train_loader), batch_time=batch_time,
                   data_time=data_time, loss=losses))
    Train_loss_list.append(losses.avg)
            
    
def validate(val_list, model, criterion):
    print ('begin test')
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset.listDataset(val_list,
                   shuffle=False,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                   ]),  train=False),
    batch_size=args.batch_size)    
    
    model.eval()
      
    
    mae = 0
    
    for i,(img, target) in enumerate(test_loader):
        img = img.cuda()
        img = Variable(img)
        output = model(img)
        
        mae += abs(output.data.sum()-target.sum().type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda())
        
    mae = mae/len(test_loader)    
    print(' * MAE {mae:.3f} '
              .format(mae=mae))
    #Val_MAE_list.append(mae)

    return mae    
        
def adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch):
    """Sets the learning rate to the initial LR decayed by 10 every 30 epochs"""
    
    
    args.lr = args.original_lr
    
    for i in range(len(args.steps)):
        
        scale = args.scales[i] if i < len(args.scales) else 1
        
        
        if epoch >= args.steps[i]:
            args.lr = args.lr * scale
            if epoch == args.steps[i]:
                break
        else:
            break
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        param_group['lr'] = args.lr
        
class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() 


"Model.py" 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torchvision import models
from utils import save_net,load_net

class CSRNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, load_weights=False):
        super(CSRNet, self).__init__()
        self.seen = 0
        self.frontend_feat = [64,64,'M',128,128,'M',256,256,256,'M',512,512,512]
        self.backend_feat  = [512, 512, 512,256,128,64]
        self.frontend = make_layers(self.frontend_feat)
        self.backend = make_layers(self.backend_feat,in_channels = 512,dilation = True)
        self.output_layer = nn.Conv2d(64, 1, kernel_size=1)
        if not load_weights:
            mod = models.vgg16(pretrained = True)
            self._initialize_weights()
            for i in range(len(self.frontend.state_dict().items())):
                list(self.frontend.state_dict().items())[i][1].data[:] = list(mod.state_dict().items())[i][1].data[:]
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.frontend(x)
        x = self.backend(x)
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x
    def _initialize_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.normal_(m.weight, std=0.01)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            
                
def make_layers(cfg, in_channels = 3,batch_norm=False,dilation = False):
    if dilation:
        d_rate = 2
    else:
        d_rate = 1
    layers = []
    for v in cfg:
        if v == 'M':
            layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        else:
            conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=3, padding=d_rate,dilation = d_rate)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            in_channels = v
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)  


"val.py" 
# To test single_image.py
import h5py
import scipy.io as io
import PIL.Image as Image
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
import scipy
import json
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F
from matplotlib import cm as CM
from image import *
from model import CSRNet
import torch
from matplotlib import cm as c

from torchvision import datasets, transforms

transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
                   ])

model = CSRNet()

#defining the model

model = model.cuda()

#loading the trained weights

checkpoint = torch.load('0PartB_BEST.pth.tar')

model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])

img = transform(Image.open('Shanghai/part_B_final/test_data/images/IMG_30.jpg').convert('RGB')).cuda()


output = model(img.unsqueeze(0))

print("Predicted Count : ", int(output.detach().cpu().sum().numpy()))

temp = np.asarray(output.detach().cpu().reshape(output.detach().cpu().shape[2],output.detach().cpu().shape[3]))

plt.imshow(temp, cmap = c.jet)

plt.show()

temp = h5py.File('Shanghai/part_B_final/test_data/ground_truth/IMG_30.h5', 'r')

temp_1 = np.asarray(temp['density'])

plt.imshow(temp_1,cmap = c.jet)

print("Original Count : ",int(np.sum(temp_1)) + 1)

plt.show()

print("Original Image")

plt.imshow(plt.imread('Shanghai/part_B_final/test_data/images/IMG_30.jpg'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your model supposed to do? You need to define clearly how to identify a True Positive, False Positive and so forth.

Comment: @jorj9 the model only calculate the MAE and MSE now I want to evaluate the model performance by precision recall and f1 measure